# Does Automatic Revalidation work for F2 visas?

Tags: visas, usa

The [official website](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/visa-information-resources/visa-expiration-date/auto-revalidate.html) says that "F and J nonimmigrants" are eligible for Automatic Revalidation provided certain conditions are met. It does not specify whether people on an F2 visa are eligible. 
But one eligibility requirement is this:

> The underlying authorization for the current status continues to be valid for the Form I-129 for non-immigrant workers and Form I-20 for students in F status.

Since F2 people don't have I-20, does it mean that they are not eligible for Automatic Revalidation? Is it explicitly stated somewhere?

Comment: "Since F2 people don't have I-20" I thought they usually do.

Comment: I thought only F1 students do, but I've never dealt with F2 and I must be mistaken.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

F-2 nonimmigrants are a subclass of F nonimmigrants, so they are indeed eligible for automatic revalidation because they are included in the statement about "F and J nonimmigrants."  Of course, the other conditions also must be met.  For an F-2 nonimmigrant, the I-20 of the principal F-1 student from whom the F-2 derives his or her status must be valid, and the F-1 student must not have violated status otherwise.